# AT86RF233 not achieving PLL lock

Tags: zigbee

I have a project based on the [ATSAMR21E17A](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/SAM-R21_Datasheet.pdf) on a custom PCB. Three prototypes were made. A software stack was made by hand from the R21 datasheet. The software stack is capable of moving the radio through its states using the TRX command (the s/w sets the TRX command through the Basic Operating Mode and reads back successful transitions).

The boards cannot achieve a PLL lock, as indicated in the IRQ_STATUS register. Both PLL_LOCK and PLL_UNLOCK bits remain zero after commanding the chip to go to PLL_ON. The external voltages are all as expected. An external 16 MHz crystal is showing a good waveform. The software enables the interrupts for PLL_LOCK, PLL_UNLOCK and TRX_END, and thus I can watch the status of the PLL lock.

Replacing processors and increasing the size of bypass caps had no effect.

The datasheet doesn't really talk about this scenario. Para 38.7.5 says PLL_UNLOCK occurs when either a manual calibration or frequency change is commanded while in PLL_ON/RX_ON. In my case, neither is applicable - frequency setting is made during device startup and not changed once the radio goes to PLL_ON/RX_ON, and manual calibrations are never commanded in these tests. In my case, PLL_UNLOCK remaining 0 seems to indicate a failure to achieve a lock in the first place, and thus PLL_UNLOCK doesn't apply because it was never locked to begin with.

The steps for a PLL_ON command are found in the datasheet at para 36.1.2.6. Upon a PLL_ON command, the AVREG is enabled, the PLL frequency synthesizer is enabled, and once the PLL is at the desired frequency, the interrupt PLL_LOCK is triggered. How this process can be interrupted or be unsuccessful is not mentioned.

The project was tested with a new board with an [AT86RF233](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-8351-MCU_Wireless-AT86RF233_Datasheet.pdf) chip on it, and communicating to that chip in an off-board manner. The results were the same: no PLL lock.

A test was done by commanding manual calibrations for CF and DCU. The DCU calibration appears to never end. All the datasheet says about this is that it ends in a couple of microseconds, and does not discuss the scenario of it continuing forever.

Thus the question is: how does one debug a failure to achieve PLL_LOCK? Has anyone run into this issue and found possible reasons? Hardware or software reasons?

Cross post to [avrfreaks](https://community.atmel.com/forum/at86rf233-failure-lock-pll), as that post did not receive any responses to date.

Comment: Have you read appendix C?

Comment: @Andyaka Hmm - that is definitely worth a try.  I note that errata is in the AT86RF233 datasheet but not in the SAMR21 datasheet.  Rather upsetting.

Comment: Implementing the errata fix did not change the situation. Interestingly, writing to the PLL_CR register and then reading it back yields a different value, like my written value is being rejected.  The chip sets it to 7, I set it to 6 and write as per the errata guidance, and then read back a 7.